# CUPS rejects username/password; what type of username/password is it expecting?

Tags: arch-linux, printing, cups

I cannot delete a printer using the CUPS system-config-printer utility. When I try to delete a printer it prompts for a username/password. However, when entering my username and password it says the authentication failed. I am a sudoer on the machine in question. What username/password is it expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Look in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` (or just `/etc/cupsd.conf`) for a stanza like:

```xml
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
```

This says who can do `CUPS-Delete-Printer`, namely users in cups group *SYSTEM*.

Look in `/etc/cups/cups-files.conf` (or similar) for the definition of this group, eg:

```
# Administrator user group, used to match @SYSTEM in cupsd.conf policy rules...
# This cannot contain the Group value for security reasons...
 SystemGroup sys root wheel
```

Here, you must be in group sys, root, or wheel.

Comment: Ok, if it says root, I assumed that sudo works. Do I actually have to login as root? I thought that sudo effectively had root credentials for purposes like this.

Comment: `sudo` might be good enough to run `system-config-printer`, but since it suppresses some environment variables you may need to carry these over somehow.